# Page loses alignment when back end is called and takes some time to re-align controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, html

I have hosted a website.
In some pages, the page shakes very badly when controls are clicked.
The link is 
http://www.pingtoday.com/Shop/ShopPage.aspx?ShopID=25

If you try to click SEND OFFER button the page completely loses its alignment for
few seconds and then re-aligns.
How to avoid this action.
Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the page gets reloaded when you click Send Offer button. You should add a quick check if a visitor is logged in or not before you send the form. So if a visitor is **not** authorized then show login form, if he is authorized - send the form. You should pass the login status variable to the template or whatever and check it with Javascript.